# Unable to translate error message when post contains a non-https image

Tags: bug, ssl, localization, imgur

If you place the following code into the post body:

> ```
> [![text][1]][1]
> [1]: http://1
> ```

you will see an error message:

> [image: error]

Text of this message is not available to translate via Transifex.

> ```
> All image URLs must start with https://
> Upload to imgur or specify an HTTPS URL
> ```